# How do modules installation work in Python?

Tags: python, installation, package, environment

[On a mac] 
I know I can get packages doing pip install etc.
But I'm not entirely sure how all this works.
Does it matter which folder my terminal is in when I write this command? 
What happens if I write it in a specific folder?
Does it matter if I do pip/pip3?

I'm doing a project, which had a requirements file. 
So I went to the folder the requirements txt was in and did pip install requirements, but there was a specific tensorflow version, which only works for python 3.7. So I did """python3.7 -m pip install requirements""" and it worked (i'm not sure why). Then I got jupyter with brew and ran a notebook which used one of the modules in the requirements file, but it says there is no such module.

I suspect packages are linked to specific versions of python and I need to be running that version of python with my notebook, but I'm really not sure how. Is there some better way to be setting up my environment than just blindley pip installing stuff in random folders?

I'm sorry if this is not a well formed question, I will fix it if you let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Setup an virtual environment.

```
pip install virtualenv #installs the library
virtualenv mypython #creates the environment
source mypython/bin/activate #activates the environment
```

Now, install your requirements through `pip`.

Afterwards, when your work is finished.

Just type `deactivate` to come out of the virtual environment.

Comment: Ok, I will try this, thanks a lot. Does it matter which folder I install virtualenv in? Can I just do it in the the file that has the requirements?

Comment: You can create a virtual environment anywhere, but I guess in your case, create it in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a difference between `pip` and `pip3`, depending on what you have installed on your system.  `pip` is likely the pip used for python2 while `pip3` is used for python3.

The easiest way to tell is to simply  execute `python` and see what version starts.  `python` will run typically run the older version 2.x python and `python3` is required to run python version 3.x.  If you install into the python2 environment (using `pip install` or `python -m pip install` the libraries will be available to the python version that runs when you execute `python`.  To install them into a python3 environment, use `pip3` or `python3 -m pip install`.

Basically, pip is writing module components into a library path, where `import <module>` can find them.  To do this for ALL users, use python3 or pip3 from the command line.  To test it out, or use it on an individual basis, use a virtual environment as @Abhishek Verma said.